# Open only local drives in open file dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to open a "OpenFileDialog", on which we can select only local hard drives (ex. C:\,D:). I want to add restrictions to access network drives. I have used following code but I am able to access the network drive.

Code is given below:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.CustomPlaces.Clear();
            foreach (DriveInfo Drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                {
                    dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(Drive.Name);
                }
            }
            dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to restrict network drives? What problem are you trying to solve/prevent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the built-in [`OpenfileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx). Changing the [`CustomPlaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.customplaces.aspx) is just the list of "custom" places you want pinned on the top left. It doesn't limit the places they can go.

I think you'll have to either write a custom dialog (ick!) or do something to validate their selection after they've hit ok.